# Jquery - date gives invalid format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea why this code returns invalid format?>

```
var utc = new Date(utc_datetime_str);
```

where utc_datetime_str is "2016/02/22 12:08 +00:00"

But this is ok: 
"2016/02/22 12:08 UTC"

Any ideas how to fix this behaviour?

edit here is the console output when a run a few commands:

```
utc_datetime_str
>>"2016/02/22 12:39 +00:00"
var utc = new Date(utc_datetime_str);
>>undefined
utc
>>[date] Invalid Date
utc_datetime_str
>>"2016/02/22 12:39 +00:00"
```

It doesn't seem to like the '+00:00' so I guess I could replace it?  As if you remove it then it works

Comment: What is the invalid format?

Comment: when i do: 

var utc = new Date("2016/02/22 12:08 +00:00"); 
alert(utc);

everything is ok, no invalid format ...

Comment: utc becomes "Invalid Date", but your right I tried it out in JSfiddle and it works.  But in IE11 I am getting invalid date returned, I set a breakpoint in console and var utc becomes "Invalid Date".  Why could this be?  string date being passed in is:  utc_datetime_str "2016/02/22 12:39 +00:00"

Comment: I guess the format of utc_datetime_str is wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: it is just in IE11 this is not working. If you create a fiddle and run it in IE it fails with invalid date.

Comment: IE seems to have trouble with the `:` inside the offset. If that is omitted it seems to work (e.g. `2016/02/22 12:08 +0000`), (tested in FF and IE)

Comment: If an offset with `:` is your input, you could use `new Date(utc_datetime_str.replace(/(\+\d+):(\d+)/,'$1$2') )` to remove only the colon after the `+`. (not that familiar with JS regex, there probably are better ways, but it works when testing)